# Why define empty state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I saw a component with a defined empty state.

```
export default class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }
 ...
```

A little lower I saw this:

```
onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpenDialog: true })}
```

Considering that the initial state has no keys, why would it be defined? I couldn't find any info on necessity of defined state for `setState`.

Does that mean that the empty state can be safely deleted, because `setState` creates it, if not initially found?

Comment: It isn't. This is useless. [`ReactBaseClass`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js) already define the initial state as an empty object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not required. The best practice is to define your state and initialize the keys you will set later on with `setState` (eg: `this.state = {isOpenDialog:false};`). Doing so will make your app function more predictably, but like I said, its not required.

An empty state object in the constructor is useless, but initializing a state object with keys set to an empty string, false, etc is not useless.

---

**Update 3/2020:**

I've been looking into this and I don't think this is correct, or at least it isn't anymore.

It appears that React actually [sets `this.state` to `null`](https://github.com/gaearon/react/blob/d385fe342809e33b92022c47ee0f7ff09ce7920c/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.js#L492) if no other value is given; **not an empty object**. There is still no restriction to updating state from null to an object later on with `setState` like in the question, but if you try to access a state property before that time, it would break.

For example, this breaks because we try to access a property of `null`:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  render (){
    return (
       <div>
         {this.state.show ? <h1>Hi!</h1> : null}
         <button onClick={this.handleChange}>Show</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

But this will not:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }

  handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      show: !this.state.show
    });
  }

  render (){
    return (
       <div>
         {this.state.show ? <h1>Hi!</h1> : null}
         <button onClick={this.handleChange}>Show</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

So in conclusion: I no longer believe this is useless, even though I maintain that it is not *required*. Keeping your datatypes consistent throughout the component lifecycle is always a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer, much appreciated.